# Need to edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf from a live CD

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hp, external-monitor

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on an HP Laptop with Nvidia Graphics hardware.  This machine used to run Ubuntu 10.10 and I have to use an external monitor as the internal screen on the laptop is broken and cannot be read.  Using the LiveCD to install 12.04 and erase the previous 10.10 installation, all worked fine while installing from the live CD and the external monitor was detected and could be used.  After finishing the install, and rebooting, the laptop will not recognize the external monitor and since the internal screen is unusable I cannot configure displays as one normally would.  I think I may be able to alter my /etc/X11/xorg.conf file to use the external monitor instead of the default device, but I am unsure of what to change in the file.  My /etc/X11/xorg.conf file looks like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier         "Default Device"
        Option "NoLogo"            "True"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the proprietary driver will still using the Live CD (should work if you have enough ram) this will install nvidia-xconfig which you will need to run as root so type the following:

sudo nvidia-xconfig -o ./xorg.conf

This will give you a more detailed xorg.conf file that should have both the broken and working monitor listed.

Below is what it added on my system. I doubt our systems are similar enough to just copy and paste what I have, but you can see in the "Screen" section it lists Monitor0 connected to Screen0 I would suspect you could change this to Monitor1.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
   VendorName     "Unknown"
   ModelName      "Unknown"
   HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
   VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
   Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier     "Screen0"
   Device         "Device0"
   Monitor        "Monitor0"
   DefaultDepth    24
   SubSection     "Display"
     Depth       24
 EndSubSection
```

EndSection

When you've made the changes copy ./xorg.conf to your harddrives /etc/X11/ directory.

Reboot and hopefully its fixed.

Comment: I'm thinking this might work.  I assume you mean using the LiveCD to install the NVIDIA drivers on the installed system, is this correct?  Also, does the LiveCD need to be rewritable in order to do this?

Comment: Also, the command to install the proprietary driver would be sudo apt-get install nvidia-xconfig?

Comment: I am unsure of how to install the proprietary driver from the Live CD.

Comment: Not exactly, you can install the nvidia drivers while still in the live CD system using the "additional drivers" program or via the command line sudo apt-get install nvidia-current. Though you can install the driver on the harddrive via the live-CD (not easy though) how would you execute it with a broken monitor...

Comment: user63668: the external monitor works when the liveCD is running. If i can get the config file like above and edit it to only use the external monitor I will not have this problem.

Comment: There is a generic driver that is loaded when using a live CD that mirrors the image on every video output. The reason it doesn't work when its installed is ,ironically, because its using the "proper" driver. I changed my profile I'm user63668 by the way :-)

Comment: I reformatted my first answer to make it easier to read.

Comment: SomKit: I changed the config file and saved it to my hard drive's proper location, but nothing changed on reboot. Here's how I installed the driver: From a LiveCD, I ran sudo apt-get install nvidia-current.  When the installation was complete, I ran the command in your original answer: sudo nvidia-xconfig -o ./xorg.conf and used the generated xorg.conf file to modify my HDD's file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf and save it running gedit as root. The changes saved but the display did not.

Comment: I suspect the changes to the xorg.config file did nothing because the nvidia driver was not installed on the computer's HDD.  Is this right?

Comment: Ahh yes of course. Did It not drop to a command line? Try hiting ctrl+alt+f1

Comment: I have rebooted into a LiveCD and verified the file was edited and saved on my HDD.  However, after running the command in your first answer, it gives WARNING: unable to locate/open X configuration file. New X configuration file written to '.xorg.conf'.    That's the file I used to edit the one on my HDD. Changed Monitor0 to Monitor1 in Screen section as suggested.

Comment: yes! ctrl+alt+f1 dropped me to command line. The command prompt is ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  How to proceed from here?

Comment: Live CD or installed system?

Comment: I used ctrl+alt+f1 from the live CD, and it opened a command promt as above. I have no idea if I am still in the live cd or the installed system.

Comment: Its a shame I can't chat... need to spend more time on here I guess.

Comment: Your still in the live CD. Okay I'm going to add the next step as an answer apposed to a comment since I left out it out above.

Comment: to get back to the desktop you can hit ctrl+alt+f7 or f8

Answer (score 1):

The system will still need to have the nvidia driver installed which the above answer fails to mention. Here is how it is done.

From the live CD Open a terminal window ctrl+alt+t or drop to a console ctrl+alt+f1. Now type:

```
sudo apt-get download nvidia-current
```

once complete make sure your harddrive is mounted it will be under /media/"whatever" type:

```
sudo dpkg --root=/media/"whatever" -i ./nvidia-current*
```

This should install the driver on the harddrive.

Reboot the system

Comment: Encountered lots of errors while processing, could not create /dev/null access denied.  No change after reboot either, and I verified that the file was still edited before rebooting.

Comment: We'll get it fixed one way or another. Try hitting ctrl+alt+f1 once ubuntu has booted on the laptop. Not the Live CD. Oh and does it display the splash screen as its booting?

Comment: Logging into the laptop with only the (broken) internal display is almost impossible. I can't tell what's going on on the laptop screen at all. It's either purple or black.

Comment: So the external display doesn't initialize at all when the computer is booting?

Comment: Negative. The external display only shows up when booting from the liveCD.

Comment: Okay I have a laptop that has nvidia chipset I'm going to reboot it and see what happens. In the mean time try editing the xorg.conf file again but replacing the driver "nvidia" with driver "nv" or driver "vesa" You have tried hitting the laptops monitor switch button haven't you?

Comment: The laptop's monitor switch button does nothing, and I have researched and tried several different combinations.  Changing the driver to "nv" or "vesa" (tried both) also did not work.  I am going to try a different version of Ubuntu or perhaps Mint I think.  I appreciate all your help.

Comment: No problem though I would expect that the issue is, again, the auto config in Xorg. I doubt that anything based on Ubuntu 12.04 will have any better luck so stick with the older distros. Good luck, its been fun.

Comment: Installing Linux Mint 12 now, which is built on Ubuntu 11.10.  If that doesn't work I'm putting Ubuntu 10.10 back on this box.  Thanks again for all your help.